# How to debug dll in lazarus

Tags: lazarus

I am creating a dll by lazarus and calling from another host application creating by lazarus too.

I config the debug compile option with above two projects:

[image]

and set `Host Application` in `Run parameters` with dll project:
[image]

and click `F9` in the dll project, the Host application is started.  However, execution of the dll project does not stop at a breakpoint I set in the dll project.

Comment: What do you mean by "but not works that cannot trigger the breakpoint set in dll project"?

Comment: it means breakpoint not work

Comment: Try setting the project options to build the dll binary direct to the same host application dir. Seems that you cannot copy/rename/move dll file.